# What is the cost of living in Dublin?

Tags: budget, dublin

I am going to be spending next week in Dublin on vacation (in February, I know). I wanted to know the cost of living in Ireland. Last I looked, the conversion between the US dollar and Euro was 1 USD = .95 Euros. So for sake of simplicity, let's say it one-to-one. Can I eat for the same amount in Dublin as I do in the US? I understand that eating in New York City is very different than eating in El Paso, Texas.

Comment: https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/compare_cities.jsp?country1=Ireland&country2=United+States&city1=Dublin&city2=New+York%2C+NY&tracking=getDispatchComparison

Comment: [Read this](http://www.irishcentral.com/travel/travel-tips/doing-dublin-on-the-cheap-wine-dine-and-make-merry-photos) I can vouch for Brasserie Sixty6 (but won't reveal where I do my drinking). Sláinte.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell if travel location is "affordable"?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69488/how-to-tell-if-travel-location-is-affordable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternative from [Expatistan](https://www.expatistan.com/cost-of-living/comparison/new-york-city/dublin) (the food part):

[image: Food prices]

Answer (score 4):

Thank you @JonathanReez for the website.

> Consumer Prices in New York, NY are 28.27% higher than in Dublin
>
> Consumer Prices Including Rent in New York, NY are 56.50% higher than
>   in Dublin
>
> Rent Prices in New York, NY are 105.54% higher than in Dublin
>
> Restaurant Prices in New York, NY are 19.80% higher than in Dublin
>
> Groceries Prices in New York, NY are 63.52% higher than in Dublin
>
> Local Purchasing Power in New York, NY is 3.38% higher than in Dublin][1](https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/compare_cities.jsp?country1=Ireland&country2=United%20States&city1=Dublin&city2=New%20York%2C%20NY&tracking=getDispatchComparison)

Data as of February 27, 2017.